# How can a Bayeux Client stop receiving messages from Bayeux Server? Is there a way to block the channel between client and server at the client side?

Tags: cometd, bayeux

At the server, CometD  provides a MaxQueueListener hook to drop messages but if  the Bayeux Client wants to stop receiving messages from a server without disconnecting , can it achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

A `BayeuxClient` receives message from the server only for the channels it is subscribed to.

For a `BayeuxClient` to stop receiving messages from the server is enough to unsubscribe from all channels it subscribed to.

The `BayeuxClient` will still receive `meta` messages on `meta` channels that are part of the Bayeux protocol, but no application message will be delivered by the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to unsubscribe from the channel because I wanted the client to receive the messages later on the  channel. I wanted a way to block the channel between Client and Server so that the server queue gets filled and Server starts dropping the messages.

Comment: If you want to receive messages later, you just resubscribe later. Why do you want to fill up the server memory with messages that the clients may never want to receive ? Alternatively, you just drop messages on the client. Another alternative is to implement this at the application level: the client tells the server that it wants to "suspend" and the server can temporarily drop messages for that client.